# How to make a timeline with data from two different objects in Angular5

Tags: angular

A simplified description of the issue.

In the backend I have two endpoints:

UserParticipation: time, userid
UserMessage: time, message, userid

These objects are shortpolled in the AngularController (with a service). So they are constantly updated.

I used to have 2 loops in the template:

```
<div *ngFor="let up of UserParticipation">
         On {{ up.time }} {{ up.userid | userlookup }} participated 
</div>
<div *ngFor="let um in UserMessage">
        On {{ um.time }} {{ um.userid | userlookup }} said {{ um.message }}
</div>
```

but I want it in a chronological (timeline) style. More like:

On 20.00 UserGary participated
On 20.05 UserMike said: "Great Work"
On 20.07 UserKarin participated
On 20.17 UserLena participated
On 20.35 UserKarin said: "Great Work"

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not sort your arrays by time in the component?

Comment: Thanx @Farasi78 , but then I still have 2 sorted arrays instead of 1...

Comment: Have your server just send back one type of object: time, message, userid. If a message doesnt exist, default it to "participated" instead of "said: {{message}}".

Comment: Can't you merge your 2 arrays into one and loop on this new array, sorting by time?

Comment: @A.Nurb, I agree with Mark, this can be solved by getting your data all in one object, unless you want to merge the two arrays and then reduce byID and sort all by time.  Would be quicker to do a query that just brings it all in together, especially if you are requesting the data in short intervals